# Print First N characters in reverse

Tags: java, import, output

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        System.out.print(sb.reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

the output should be:-

```
apple
3

ppa
```

but I'm getting full string in reverse

```
elppa
```

like this

Comment: Just substring `str` before putting it in the `StringBuilder`

Comment: What's the uses of "int N = sc.nextInt();" if you don't use N anywhere? I guess this is some "self-blind" issue you will laugh about when you look at it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't splitting the string at all in your code. What you need is a `.substring()`. Since you can't reverse a word after performing the `.substring()` on a StringBuilder, we'll just create our own reverse method. Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.print(reverse(str.substring(0, n)));
    sc.close();
  }
  public static String reverse(String text) {
    return new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();
  }
}
```

Using strictly StringBuilder methods (as you requested), you can do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitReverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        sb=new StringBuilder(sb.substring(0,n));
        System.out.println(sb.reverse());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

However, I would recommend this one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SplitReverse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.substring(0,n));
        System.out.println(sb.reverse());
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I solved the same problem, I got it right.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.substring(0,N));
        System.out.print(sb.reverse().toString());
    }
}
```